# devise for two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise

I am building an app with "nested authentication" That means that I have a House modle (with devise) and a house has many users and once inside the House authentication, I would like the users to be able to sign in as well.  I have also added a User model with Devise.  My question is that right now I am getting errors because I the devise sign_up form that I have designed for Houses doesn't work for the User model.  How do I create separate sign_up and sign_in forms for two different user models with devise?  Or is there a better way to go about doing this?  Thanks!

Comment: I've done that before, and after a lot of pain and suffering, finally went to using a single model for sign in cancan and role based authentication, of course issues with privilege escalation will occur, but I would see that as a lesser evil.

Comment: I have thought about using cancan, but the House model and the User models are very different, I guess I could assign the house attributes the the admin of each house, but this also seems messy...

Answer (score 2):

> How do I create separate sign_up and sign_in forms for two different user models with devise?

```
rails g devise:views
```

This will create an app/views/devise.

Then: set "config.scoped_views = true" inside "config/initializers/devise.rb".

From the README:

> After doing so, you will be able to have views based on the role like "users/sessions/new" and "admins/sessions/new". If no view is found within the scope, Devise will use the default view at "devise/sessions/new".