# NoMethodError in Devise/registrations#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I already have normal users signing up and signing in using devise . What i was planning on doing was make 2 categories(let's say A & B) for users . So i ran the command rails generate devise A and views for the same . When i open up A/sign_up , this is what comes up

NoMethodError in Devise/registrations#new

```
Showing /app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb where line #11 raised:

undefined method `name' for #<A:0xc654e54>

Extracted source (around line #11):

    <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :validate => true) do |f| %>

      <div>
        <%= f.text_field :name, :validate => { :presence => true }, :placeholder => 'Full Name' %>

     </div>
```

Please do suggest what's causing this to appear . Using rails 3.2.8 , devise 2.2.3 and ruby 1.9.3 . Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't think I answer this, but to help out, have you signed out? Also, try making a label called `f.label :name`. Curious on what will happen.

Comment: Both A and B, do they have `name` attribute?

Comment: @BenMorganIO - trying it out now .

Comment: Yes @Santosh , both models throw the same error .

Comment: Try `username`, i thinnk there are no `name` in devise model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

undefined method `name' for #

Means that Devise is looking for a model A that has a method or database column :name.

This will through an error unless you have a Model called A, with devise :registerable in the model definition, or is model A has no :name method of column.

Devise is typically used with a model, if you want two types of users, I suggest you make two separate models UserA and UserB and add Devise separately to each of them.

Comment: looks like that's where i was going wrong . Earlier model had name defined in it and i didn't mentioned name here . I did add :name in model A but it's still throwing the same error . Is it necessary to add the name field in the db as well ?

Comment: You should be able to create an attr_accessor :name and that will work fine.
It's preferred to have the field name in the database if you're doing f.text_field otherwise use text_field_tag

Comment: Is there a blog or something that can be helpful in achieving what i am planning to do . I tried mentioning :name in attr_accessor but it threw the same error . Dropped the db , made changes into it and now it's working fine .

Comment: To be honest I haven't really heard of someone doing that, but I imaging devise has documentation for it, that gem is so widely adopted that it shouldn't be hard to find something.

It sounds like this guy [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17463519/devise-for-two-models) recommends using cancan. I can help you out with that if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks a lot , i was looking forward to having some guidance on this . Where can i reach you ?

Comment: click on my profile, go to my about.me site and contact info shouldn't be hard to find.